# db2 execute triggers using ant script

Tags: triggers, db2

I have an sql file containing triggers. I want to execute this file using Ant script:

```
<target name="exec-sql-proc_db2" depends="init">
  <property name="project.sql.dir" value="${project.metadata.dir}/sql" />
  <property name="triggerFile" value="${project.sql.dir}/triggers_db2.sql" />
  <echo message="${triggerFile}" />
  <sql rdbms="DB2" driver="com.ibm.db2.jcc.DB2Driver" 
       url="jdbc:db2://localhost:50000/project:currentSchema=mySchema;" 
       userid="root" password="root" 
       classpath="C:\projects\myProject\lib\db2jcc.jar" 
       src="${triggerFile}" 
       onerror="${sql.onerror}" 
       keepformat="true" delimiter="/" />
</target>
```

I get build successful, but the triggers are not executed !
Is there any other solution?

my trigger is :

```
CREATE or REPLACE TRIGGER PRODUCT_HISTORY_AFTER_UPDATE
AFTER UPDATE ON PRODUCT 
REFERENCING NEW AS N 
FOR EACH ROW 
BEGIN 
   INSERT INTO productHistory ( id_h, id_product , name) values (id_h_seq.nextval, N.id_product , N.name ); 

    END 
/
```

Comment: What do you mean with "*triggers are not executed*"? A trigger is only "executed" when the corresponding DML (insert, update, delete) statement is run.

Comment: I have a trigger on a table called product, when I update a row in this product I insert into product_history,

This trigger is saved in a file, I used this script to execute the trigger, 
then when I update a row in the table product, no row is inserted in the table product_history

Comment: Did you check the trigger was actually created? Did you check the trigger was enabled/valid/active? Post the full code of the trigger and the DML statements you use.

Comment: CREATE or REPLACE TRIGGER  PRODUCT_HISTORY_AFTER_UPDATE 
AFTER UPDATE ON PRODUCT
REFERENCING NEW AS N
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
 INSERT INTO  productHistory ( id_h, id_product , name) 

(id_h_seq.nextval, N.id_product , N.name );

END

Comment: Do ***not*** post code in comments. Edit your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<sql rdbms="DB2" driver="com.ibm.db2.jcc.DB2Driver" 
       url="jdbc:db2://localhost:50000/project:currentSchema=mySchema;" 
       userid="root" password="root" 
       classpath="C:\projects\myProject\lib\db2jcc.jar" 
       src="${triggerFile}" 
       onerror="${sql.onerror}" 
        delimiter="/" >

SET SCHEMA mySchema
</sql>
```

I tried this part of code, that solves my problem